# Infinite circular carousel control for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, carousel

I am looking for infinite circular carousel control for Windows Phone 8.1. The one that can be scrolled left and right.

Comment: Like *Pivot* or *Panorama/Hub*?

Comment: I need only one image currently selected fully visible with left and right images partially visible.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at Syncfusion Carousel control:
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/carousel

But it looks like they still do not support infinite scrolling, although I have made such a feature request in the past